# Behaviour of soft links pointing to each other in unix filesystem?

Tags: linux, unix, ubuntu, operating-system, symlink

When I made two soft links in a directory pointing to each other

eg.
`abc->xyz` and `xyz->abc`

I was not able to open that directory graphically in ubuntu.
When I clicked that dierctory it instantly opened and that gets closed immediately.
what may be the reason for that and how can it be sorted except deleting those soft links?

Comment: can you try nautilus thru command line and try, you mgiht get more info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably mean circular *symbolic links* (or symlinks). What would you expect? Any [open(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/open.2.html) (or others) syscall would fail with errno set to

```
  ELOOP  Too many symbolic links encountered while traversing the path.
```

You should remove one of the links, with the [unlink(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/unlink.2.html) syscall, e.g. called by the `rm` command; so you could open a terminal, `cd` to the directory containing that mess, then

```
 rm -v abc xyz
```